Philosophy of Action 101
I am looking for a concise introductory work to the philosophy of action, to use as a background text from which to start for a work in the field of social sciences.
After extense review, I haven't found any suitable work. I have found only very specialized literature, textbooks, companions, etc.
Could anyone recommend an authoritative, sound, well structured, complete yet concise (around 20 pages) work providing an introduction and full overview of the philosophy of action, including well-established and generally accepted ideas, suitable for non-specialists?
Thanks in advance.

This? https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/action/

Moya, The Philosophy of Action: An Introduction:"This new textbook is an exceptionally clear and concise introduction to the philosophy of action, suitable for students interested in the philosophy of mind and the philosophy of social sciences."
